# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' in javascript

Tags: javascript

this is my code in ajax
when i looping the result to create array of objects i found this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/GetYaers",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        /*alert(response);*/
        Morris.Bar({
            element: 'morris_bar',
            data: $.each(response.data, function (index, value) {
                { x: value.donationYear, y: value.amount };
            }),
            xkey: 'x',
            ykeys: ['y'],
            labels: ['Y'],
            barColors: ['#5969ff'],
            resize: true,
            gridTextSize: '14px'
        });
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert("failure");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyhQl.png)

i try to looping the result of response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense in two ways:

```
data: $.each(response.data, function (index, value) {
    { x: value.donationYear, y: value.amount };
})
```

First, the line of code `{ x: value.donationYear, y: value.amount };` is just plain invalid.  It looks like you're creating an object literal, but by itself as a line of code that wouldn't do anything.  (And the syntax parsing doesn't expect it, which is producing the error.)

Second, `$.each()` has no return value.  So what is being set to the `data` property here?

It *looks like* you meant to *map* over your array and *return* an object literal for each element in that array.  For example:

```
data: response.data.map(function (value) {
    return { x: value.donationYear, y: value.amount };
})
```